# Why does a hash value change while hashing from different file formats?

Tags: python, hash, cryptography, digital-signature, sha256

I have observed that when I hash data from a *.txt file and a *.docx file the both hash generated are different even though the data is same in both the file.
Why does this happen?

Comment: What is the character encoding used in both these cases?

Comment: how do you know its the same? I have written the word hello in a txt file and a docx. The text file is 1kb and the docx is 12kb so clearly while the content is the same the docx will probably be saving a lot more data related to the document and its formatting.

Comment: You are wrong: "the data is same in both the files". Opened they look similar but they are not the same! Anyway hashing works on the file data (bytes) not on the "content".

Answer (score 1):

You can only hash a representation of a value in the form of a chunk of bytes. So even if you represent precisely the same value as two different chunks of bytes, they will not have the same hash. If you need them to be the same, then you must convert the representation you get the value in into a canonical representation.

You have this issue any time there's some information in the representation that is extraneous to the value. For example, these two strings will definitely have different hashes:

```
{ "id" : 1, "value" : "moo" }
```

and:

```
{ "value" : "moo", "id" : 1 }
```

However, in JSON, they represent precisely the same value. If they didn't encode JSON objects, it would be critical that they hashed differently. If they do encode JSON, it's critical that they hash the same. But, of course, the hashing algorithm has no idea whether the thing it's hashing encodes JSON or not. So this cannot possibly be the hashing algorithm's responsibility.

You need code to ensure that two different representations of the same value present the same representation to the hashing algorithm. This is your responsibility -- the hashing algorithm can't possibly do it.

Answer (score 0):

Cryptographic Hash functions are in a sense random but deterministic functions. Deterministic means the same values will result in the same hash values. They are random in the sense that the value of the hash is unpredictable.

Your txt and docx files, although have the same text, in the binary they will be different. You can compare them with the `diff` command and see the difference. Also, you can see that they will have different file sizes.

As long as you are not very lucky, we don't expect that you find a collision that is two different inputs have the same value.

Comment: pretty sure hash functions don't involve "randomness"!  unpredictable is a much better term, maybe just stick with that?

Comment: @SamMason Random is explained in the second sentence. `They are random in the sense that the value of the hash is unpredictable.`